# How to attach request params in spring which is retrieved from front end?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I tried this code below...can anyone kindly help me how to pass the params to the spring method and is it a correct implementation in angularjs.

```
@GetMapping("/extended-registered-time")
public ResponseEntity<List<Registered_time>> getSubLeaves(@ApiParam Pageable pageable) {
  log.debug("REST request to get registered time : {}", pageable);
  LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2018,01,15);
  LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2018,01,24);
  List<Registered_time> result = ExtendedRegisteredTimeService.
    getSelectedRegisteredTime(startDate,endDate);
  return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This is the frontend implementation(AngularJs)

```
 .factory('RegisteredTimeService', RegisteredTimeService);

RegisteredTimeService.$inject = ['$resource'];

function RegisteredTimeService ($resource) {

    var userName="HGajanayake";

    var resourceUrl =  '/api/extended-registered-time/{'+userName+'}';

    return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
        'query': {

            method: 'GET',

            isArray: true
        },

        'status':{
            method:"POST",
            isArray:true,
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt get over with @requestParams so I choosed @pathVariable instead.I got the correct result.

This is my Service

```
  function RegisteredTimeService ($resource) {

        var userName="HGajanayake";



       // var resourceUrl =  '/api/extended-registered-time?employee='+userName;
        var resourceUrl =  "/api/extended-registered-time/:employee";
        return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
            'query': {

                method: 'GET',

                isArray: true
            },
```

This is my api endpoint

```
  @GetMapping("/extended-registered-time/{employee}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<Registered_time>> getSubLeaves(@PathVariable String employee) {



        List<Registered_time> result = ExtendedRegisteredTimeService.getSelectedRegisteredTime(employee);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

This is the controller where I call the service

```
function RegisteredTimeController ($rootScope, $scope, $state, Employee, RegisteredTimeService,Profile,$resource) {
        var firstName="HGajanayake";


      var c=RegisteredTimeService.query({employee:firstName},function(result) {
          var v=result;
            console.log(v);
        });
```